# jQuery $.get - automate params

Tags: jquery, get

Is there any way to automate adding params into jQuery $.get ?

**For the moment I'm listing those by hand - but what would I do if the form has 100s of fields?**

Please see my comment in the code belowe.

**$.get:**

```
                // How to automate this?
                var ContactName = $('#contact-name').val();                                       
                var ContactEmail = $('#contact-email').val();
                var ContactPhone = $('#contact-phone').val();
                var ContactMessage = $('#contact-message').val();

                $.get("contact-form.php", {

                    // How to automate this?
                    ContactName: ContactName,
                    ContactEmail: ContactEmail,
                    ContactPhone: ContactPhone,
                    ContactMessage: ContactMessage

                }, function() {}).success(function() {

                    // Do  stuff once email send
                })
```

Comment: If you had a form with hundreds of fields I'd say you need to change your form. 1 form field is 1 too many, let alone hundreds.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon - 100s in the principal. But I'm expecting more than 30(data collecting and analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use $("#myForm").serialize().
see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$.get("contact-form.php",$("#myForm").serialize(), function() {}).success(function() {
   // Do  stuff once email send
});
```

you can also use serializeArray() if you want to manually add some parameters to the serialized form, see http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

```
var params = $("#myForm").serializeArray();
params.push({ name : "custom", value : "toto"});
$.get("contact-form.php",params, function() {}).success(function() {
       // Do  stuff once email send
});
```

Comment: Looks good! Do you know by any chance is there similar way to receive the data in PHP? My PHP file looks like that at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/mgxbe/

Comment: You could probably loop on the request parameters, but there will be no way to assure the order of the parameters in the loop... and doing batch work on received data seems... strange. Anyway, I don't use PHP so cannot really help.

Comment: Thank for the time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Use serialize()

```
$("#formID").serialize();
```

Comment: @NewUser: Yo've got an example there

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to retrieve the values before mutting them into the data object, just load them straight in.

```
            $.get("contact-form.php", {
                ContactName: $('#contact-name').val(),
                ContactEmail: $('#contact-email').val(),
                ContactPhone: $('#contact-phone').val(),
                ContactMessage: $('#contact-message').val()
            }, function() {}).success(function() {
                // Do  stuff once email send
            })
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to list them - is there a way to automate the process?